# How to initialize wow.js in infinite scroll callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, css-animations, infinite-scroll

I want to initialize wow.js in a callback so that the animation will work on each new item as they are retrieved.

HTML

```
<div class="itemWrapper wow">
/// content
</div>
```

Infinite scroll

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // Infinite Scroll
    $('#prod-container').infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '.pageNavigation a',    
      nextSelector : '.pageNavigation a.next', 
      itemSelector : '.itemWrapper', 
      animate      : true,
      bufferPx     : 10,
      loading: {
          finishedMsg: '<div class="thumb-scroll"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></div>',
          img: 'images/ajax-loader.gif',
          pixelsFromNavToBottom: 0
       }
     });

});
```

Wow.js

```
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>

<script>

$('.itemWrapper').addClass('animated bounceIn');

new WOW().init();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### See WOW.js [Issue #71](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/71).

Your solution would almost work, but the problem is that it would re-initialise existing elements. This will work once [#71](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/71) is fixed.

---

### Update

The issue is fixed since July 2014, as [attilaolah](https://github.com/attilaolah) [wrote](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/71#issuecomment-47456120):

> Version [0.1.10](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/releases/tag/0.1.10) is out, it adds support for asynchronously loaded
>   content. You don't need to change anything in your code, just upgrade
>   to the new version.